# Transfer from Palma PMI to Port der Pollenca

Tags: airport-transfer, mallorca

My family and I will go to Mallorca next week and need to travel from PMI airport to Port de Pollenca. What is the most convenient way to get there? Is there a maximum fee taxis are allowed to charge for this trip?

Comment: There's no fixed fee for this journey if you pick up a metered taxi outside the airport. The rates are per km and per hour. I am sure you can prebook a taxi for a fixed price if that is more reassuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Palma-Mallorca-Airport-PMI/Port-de-Pollen%C3%A7a) shows a bus option, first one which takes you from the airport to Alcúdia, where you catch the [TIB linea 352 bus to Port de Pollença](https://www.tib.org/web/ctm/autobus/linia/352); the trip takes less than 2 hours.

A taxi for the 67km drive run between €70- 90 and several are listed: [Taxis Palma Radio SGL](http://www.taxispalmaradio.com/) +34 971 70 24 24 and [Mallorca Taxi](https://www.mallorca-taxi.com/) +34 607 26 62 55

Comment: We took a cab from the airport, the drivers have a sheet which shows the approximate fares. We paid about 80 per way.

Answer (score 2):

I just returned from Mallorca a week ago.

From the Airport, take the #1 bus to the [Estacion Intermodal](https://www.google.com/maps/@39.5763715,2.6547322,18.42z) at the Plasa de Espanya.  That should cost €5,00 per person, and takes about 30 minutes.

Inside the Station find the bus #340 to Pollenca.
I believe it cost €5,00 each, and took one hour, with about 4 or 5 quick stops along the way.

Here's the matching [Google Directions](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Palma+de+Mallorca+Airport,+07611+Palma,+Illes+Balears,+Spain/Port+de+Pollen%C3%A7a,+Spain/@39.7183874,2.7274522,10.75z/am=t/data=!4m17!4m16!1m5!1m1!1s0x1297942ff5db35f3:0x7031da6569b7f956!2m2!1d2.7361649!2d39.5517407!1m5!1m1!1s0x1297d4d9be37988b:0xa02af717f573f90!2m2!1d3.0824071!2d39.9074062!2m2!7e2!8j1506076200!5i2).

A taxi would cost you MUCH MUCH more, and barely be any faster at all.

The transportation website https://www.tib.org/en/ is very good, and supports multiple languages.

Comment: This is definitely a useful answer, but in the interests of keeping it up to date I would comment that the #1 bus between the airport and the Plaza de España now costs 5€. I'm not sure why the price jumped so much in a few months.

Comment: I may have been wrong in the first place:   I took a lot of buses while I was there.  Most of them were 1,50, but a few had higher prices.  The airport bus may have been one with extra costs.